# print icon and text for ActionLink ASP.NET razor code

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor

i am using ActionLink to print icon and hyperlink text... which is working fine but my text is appearing on icon...

```
@Html.ActionLink("New FreeZone", "CreateNewFreeZone", "Qualification", null, new { @class = "CreateNewEntry_Icon" })
```

### CSS

```
 .CreateNewEntry_Icon{ 
 height:24px;
 display:inline-block;
 background:url("../ImagesAndIcons/Icons/Add_New.png") no-repeat top left;
 }
```

Comment: i have introduce two classes, when i apply css to one; it applies to icon as well....

Comment: I'd actually add padding rather than margin to allow space for the icon - the background will be within the border of the element rather than outside (where the margin will be added). It is also more flexible than text-indent in that you can add padding both vertically and horizontally. Another advantage of padding is that, by increasing the effective offset size of the element, you are increasing the touch area for your button or link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add line-height in your CSS

```
.CreateNewEntry_Icon{ 
 line-height:5; //Adjust Accordingly
 display:inline-block;
 background:url("../ImagesAndIcons/Icons/Add_New.png") no-repeat top left;
 }
```

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F3z9R/)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to have two separate items, it is always difficult to arrange the icon as you want so by keeping it separate it will solve you problem as well as gives you the freedom to position you image and text of your choice. you can write your razor style for these elements

```
<div>
   <img style="width:30px;height:60px;vertical-align:middle">
   <span style="">Works.</span>
</div
```